# Why does Python 3.7 runtime on Google Cloud Function not allow slackclient anymore?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, slack-api

I'm trying to deploy a Python 3.7 runtime Google Cloud Function to send a message via the Slack API. However, I keep getting the same error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'". This functionality was working well 6 months ago. For testing purposes, I created a test function which simply imports the slackclient package and prints "success" upon doing so. However, this results in the same error message.

Please find below: copy of error message and screenshots of `main.py` and `requirements.txt`. Any ideas?

```
Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in requirements.txt?
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 305, in 
check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 184, in 
load_user_function
   spec.loader.exec_module(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import slackclient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'
```

[Screenshot of `main.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDbBX.png)

[Screenshot of `requirements.txt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmtMJ.png)

Answer (score 5):

So I'm guessing you previously had v1 of the `slackclient` library. Per the [migration to v2 docs](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/wiki/Migrating-to-2.x) and general [docs](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient#basic-usage-of-the-web-client) you now need:

`import slack`

not

`import slackclient`

Alternatively you could try adding `slackclient<2` to `requirements.txt` to make it use v1. But really I'd try and stay up to date.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yes I must've had v1.x of the `slackclient` library (without knowing it haha). I didn't know about the upgrade to version 2 and so I didn't realise they made such a drastic change in their upgrade to version 2.